# Controller not executed in my Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I tried to create simple Hello World app in Spring Boot using kotlin but IntelliJ IDE shows me warning that my controller class is never used and the specified endpoint does not work as well. I can't figure out what to do with it.

I created the app with the Boot Initializr and the structure looks like this:

```
kotlin/
    com.myapp.school/
        Application.kt
        controller/
            HelloController.kt
resources/
    static/
    templates/
        hello.html
```

And here is the code for Application.kt:

```
package com.myapp.school

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

Last, I have this simple controller with one method:

```
package com.myapp.school.controller

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.ui.Model
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping

@Controller
class HelloController

@GetMapping("/hello")
fun hello(): String {
    System.out.println("Hello from controller")

    return "hello"
}
```

Going to localhost:8080/hello shows whitelabel error page with 404 status. I read that Spring prints registered endpoints into the console at startup but I haven't found such message.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`. Your current controller will try to locate a view named `hello`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have a top level class with no body (`HelloController`) and a top level function (`hello`). You have to put curly braces to make sure `hello` is a member of `HelloController`.

You have this:

```
@Controller
class HelloController

@GetMapping("/hello")
fun hello(): String {
    System.out.println("Hello from controller")

    return "hello"
}
```

It needs to be like this, so `hello` belongs in `HelloController`, not at the same level:

```
@Controller
class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun hello(): String {
        System.out.println("Hello from controller")

        return "hello"
    }
}
```

Also, change `System.out.println` to just `println` to be more Kotlin-like.

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much. Now it works OK.